# I get the grey screen after startup on 2006 macbook pro. no keys work.

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, startup

Just a few days ago ( I have actually been using another computer for a while ) I started up my 2006  macbook pro and and after a few minutes I got the white diagonal lines, although I could still see the desktop pic with the top menu and dock but hitting keys did nothing.

Well after a few more startups in the last few days, that desktop disappeared with just the white lines across a grey screen, then the next start up the apple logo had diagonal lines and then black lines and just now I fired it up again and I got the black lines and then right to the grey screen.

I've seen this issue posted about before and I cannot remember what it means and I hope it is fixable.

It's a 2006 15" MacBook Pro. I had the video chip replaced a few years back.

So, cuz it's 9 years old and otherwise works perfectly - except that I am maxed out at OSX 10.6.8 - I wonder if it is worth fixing - depending on what needs to be done.

If it's the hard drive, I am wondering if it is worth removing it and replacing with a solid state?

Any thoughts? O and previous to this the start up sound was like a car battery that was almost dead when you start it up. really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like the graphics chip is on the blink again, it's pretty common to see these units fail again and again...

Unfortunately you won't be able to get it serviced any more as [it's classified as obsolete by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624) now so no parts are available, although maybe eBay etc...

There is a chance you could do an OS reinstall to verify it's a hardware fault and not software, but the diagonal lines is symptomatic of a hardware graphics chip issue like you would see on this range of machine.

I would be looking to replace the machine at this point sadly. It might be worth going to the manager in an Apple Store and indicating that it's failed for a known fault again and asking if they would give a discount on a new machine as they may well do this as a gesture of good will.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. I just started it up once more holding down the ALT key and it worked just fine and now on sleep.

Comment: The folks downtown who did the video chip replacement do free diagnostics. So i think I will take it in and see what they find and if it is replaceable. I cannot afford to get another Mac now.

Comment: What about the idea of replacing the hard drive with a solid state?

Comment: Oops! Well, it did. I lifted the hood to check and it looked fine for about 10 seconds, then the white lines and then the black lines.

Comment: Wait a sec, you are saying the video chip and the graphics chip are the same chip?

Comment: @sunny i wouldn't replace the disk with a solid state, yes it is faster than your current disk but i don't think that if has any benefits thanks to te processor and the current OSX you're on

Comment: Ok. It was a thought. If the video chip is the same as a graphic chip then the problem is on the logic board, not the hard drive. So putting in a solid state drive is not about this problem. And that was what was replaced two years ago. ( I found the receipts. )

Comment: Well, someone told me to start it up with Shift key in Safe Mode and it seems to be working.

Comment: Graphics/video card/chip/controller are the same.